# AspectJ not capture calls from jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I want to do specific action when `System.currentTimeMillis()` is called. I use AspectJ as below to do that.

```
public aspect CurrentTimeInMillisMethodCallChanger {
    long around(): 
    call(public static native long java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        //provide my own implementation 
    }
}
```

This program works fine when `System.currentTimeMillis()` is called in any method of the application.

However, when `System.currentTimeMillis()` is called from method inside a jar file then around is not executed. I used `within(packageofJarFile.*)`, but it does not work.

I am using Eclipse.

Please let me know what I need to add to the above code to support call from (specific) jar file as well ?

Comment: is this a new way of declaring aspects ? I have always used it in a fashion like http://eggsylife.co.uk/2010/02/03/spring-annotation-based-aop-and-intercepting-the-ball/

Comment: Got it you are using plain aspectJ though my link is about spring aspects

Comment: Yes. It is plain AspectJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the AspectJ plugin for Eclipse (AJDT), so that it weaves library code as well, not just your own class files. You can do this by going to `Project Properties -> AspectJ Build -> Inpath tab` and add the jar files you want to be weaved by your aspects. Here is a screenshot of the dialog:
[image: AJDT properties screenshot]
The library classes weaved like this will be dumped in your output classes folder unless you set up an `Output jar` on the third tab of the same properties page.